# SQL Server Syntax to select two rows of data and overwrite values that are different from the first row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
id,  Name,     LinkBackId, Param1, Param2, Param3
1,  "Name1",   NULL,       10,     20,     30    
2,  "Name2",   NULL,       10,     20,     30 
3,  "Name3",   2,          14,     NULL,   NULL
```

The LinkBackId is important here because this is associated with the id that is also in this table.  Looking at row 3 LinkBackId contains 2 I want it to return the row from id = 0 and merge the values from row 3 into the result like this:

```
3,  "Name3", 2, 10, 20, 30
```

I am treating the rows that contain NULL in the LinkBackId as a "master" row of parameters.  The rows that contain a linkbackid are to be overriden by the master values that are not NULL.

I am wondering if there is an elegant method to do this instead of using lots of if statements.

Hope this makes sense.

Thank you

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you working with? Also, how deep does the recursive lookup need to go? What if the row with `id=2` had `LinkBackId=1`?

Comment: [1] I am using SQL Server 2005.  
[2] Recursive lookup is always just one deep.  The "master" values should not have a linkbackid (hence they are NULL above).
[3] The master row (row=1) wins.
Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a query that will return the values from a row, unless it has a LinkBackId value, in which case it will use values from that row:

```
SELECT 
  t1.id,
  t1.Name,
  t1.LinkBackId,
  COALESCE(t2.Param1,t1.Param1),
  COALESCE(t2.Param2,t1.Param2),
  COALESCE(t2.Param3,t1.Param3)
FROM table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table t2
  ON t1.LinkBackId = t2.id
```

It won't work with multiple levels of nesting (i.e. if row 2 referred back to row 1). It works by using the `COALESCE` function, which returns the parameter from the primary row if there are no values in the `LinkBackId` row.

Comment: Note that if the LinkBack row param values are NULL, this query will not return them - make sure that is the desired behavior.

Comment: And if linkback values are null, above will return first row values (if they are non-null),  if values from from linkback row are desired whenever there is a linkback Id, even if linkback values are null, then better might be to use Case   ( Case when t2.Id Is Null then t1.Param1 Else t2.Param1 End )

Comment: This is perfect, thank you.  I need to test the NULL comment above.

Comment: @Welbog, Coalesce returns first non-null value in it's parameter list. If t2.Param1 is null, Coalesce(t2.Param1, t1.Param1) will return t1.Param1.

Comment: @Charles: Yeah, I misunderstood OrbMan's comment. Now that I get it, I see that it's a legitimate concern.

Comment: @WelBog, easily fixed by changing conditional Coalesce to a case which is dependant on existence of outer join key column ------ Case when t2.Id Is Null then t1.Param1 Else t2.Param1 End

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update row 2 with the values from row 3?

if so, then try this

```
Update tu Set 
    name = o.Name,
    linkbackId = o.LinkbackId,
    param1 = o.param1,
    param2 = o.param3,
    param3 = o.param3
From Table tu 
  Join Table tr
     On tr.LinkbackId = tu.Id
Where tu.id = 2
```

EDIT:  Not what you want, sorry